# I tried starting VPN, didn't set password, but later now screen is asking password. What to do?

Tags: password, vpn

I have Gionee P5L phone. I was not able to access a site, then thought on starting VPN of the phone; went to VPN, and then it asked to set any of the security: password, swipe, etc. I entered into password section, but didn't press any password, then pressed back button. Now, phone is asking password, but I didn't set any password before.

I didn't really type any password, as I remember. Same thing had happened before with my other Gionee P5W; but then I tapped on forgot password, it asked me security question and allowed me in. Here, with P5L, on tapping forgot password, it says me on me to have not set any security question and the only option as to factory reset.

What do I do to remove this password wall?

Comment: If that's a VPN app  try uninstalling that from safe mode if possible

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I didn't install VPN app, I tried starting the in-built VPN. I don't know about safe mode, I will see on whether I can remove password via it or not.

Answer (score 1):

In order to enable built-in VPN, you must put a screen pattern or pin code, that's a security feature. 
So you did put a code, just remember

Comment: NO I DIDN'T PUT A PASSWORD, I REMEMBER THAT! :)

Comment: I tired with my first 4 numbers of my phone number, it opened! If any are having this problem, try doing this.

Comment: You put your firt four numbers as password, that's a fact! This won't work for everyone having this issue .